# Android: app not returning correctly from intent

Tags: android, android-intent

I have an activity, that, when an `ImageView` is clicked, it will open a second activity for selecting and cropping an image.

This process works fine. In the second activity, when the user is satisfied with the picture, he will click `DONE`button and go back to previous activity, and the cropped image will be showed in the ImageView clicked.

**The problem:** the first activity is no longer showed after going back from second activity....in my real device, it goes back to starting Android menu, if I try to check the opened apps, my app is there, but even if I click on it again, it does not go to the first activity...seems like it repeats the process again for selecting and cropping image.....weird :S

Here is the relevant pieces of code I am using to move from one activity to another:

**On the first activity I have:**

```
public void onImageViewClicked(View v){

        this.clickedImageView = (ImageView) v;
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, CropImages.class);
        switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.imgvW_1:
                startActivityForResult(intent, 1111);
                break;
            case R.id.imgvW_2:
                startActivityForResult(intent, 2222);
                break;
            case R.id.imgvW_3:
                startActivityForResult(intent, 3333);
                break;
        }

    }
```

And the result should come here:

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK){    
            if (requestCode == 1111){
                Bitmap b = (Bitmap) data.getParcelableExtra("Image");
                img_encoded_1 = Utilities.encode64Bitmap(b);
                clickedImageView.setImageBitmap(b);


            }

        }
    }
```

**The second activity (CropImages.java) does a lot of stuff....but should end like this:**

```
public void onDoneClicked(View v){
        // cropped Bitmap stored in cropped
        Intent returnIntent = getIntent();
        returnIntent.putExtra("Image", cropped);
        setResult(RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
        finish();
    }
```

Any clue why the first activity disappears and the real device just shows the welcome/main Android screen??

If that helps: the second activity also launches an intent, for selecting an image from `Gallery` or `Camera`....I do not think that matters though....

if that helps...It seems like `onActivityResult` on the first activity is never executed...a `TOAST` on that method is never showed.

Comment: You might have clicked Debug 'app' instead of Run 'app'

Comment: yes my fault, ignore last edit...i delete...

Comment: Alright, is it working now?

Comment: nope....same situation still, after closing the second activity...back to "Android desktop"...u know what i mean

Comment: Upload the full code, including manifest

Answer (score 0):

This might be the issue, change the following in your First Activity.

```
Intent intent = new Intent({First Acticity name here}.this, CropImages.class);
```

Comment: thanks man, but isnt `this` the same as `first activity name`???, however, I tried and it does not work.....same result

Comment: I think if you use `this`, you need to specify `parentActivityname` in the manifest - [Documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html#Up)

Answer (score 0):

Change the following code

```
public void onDoneClicked(View v){
    // cropped Bitmap stored in cropped
    Intent returnIntent = getIntent();
    returnIntent.putExtra("Image", cropped);
    setResult(RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
    finish();
}
```

To

```
public void onDoneClicked(View v){
    // cropped Bitmap stored in cropped
    Intent returnIntent = new Intent();  ;
    returnIntent.putExtra("Image", cropped);
    setResult(RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
    finish();
}
```

For your reference

https://www.javatpoint.com/android-startactivityforresult-example

Comment: thanks, but I am afraid that was not the problem, it still gives the same behaviour